# Meteor: Collection loads when I navigate to a page, but not when URL is directly inputted

Tags: meteor, anchor

I'm a Meteor newb and would appreciate any help here.

I'm creating a flashcard app where you can create decks of cards. It saves the progress that one has made through a deck of cards.

It appears that when I navigate into a deck of cards by clicking on the name of a deck (a link), everything works fine. But when I directly paste the URI in, the Deck collection fails to load.

I believe that this is because of routes.js, in the lib folder, is the first to load so there is no data. I tried using the waitOn function in Router.configure, but it's still not working.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
 Router.route ('/:_id/:wordIndex', {
        template: 'wordPage',

        data: function () { 
            var index = this.params.wordIndex;
            var id = this.params._id;

            console.log(Decks);
            var word = Decks.findOne ( id, 
                        { fields: { 'wordIds': 1 } } 
                    ); 
            }
        }
    );
```

I tried using the waitOn function within the router already as well:

```
Router.configure ( {
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    waitOn: function () { return [
        Meteor.subscribe ('words'),
        Meteor.subscribe ('decks')
    ]}
})
```

**EDIT**

Ok, it seems like I found a solution by getting the data client side instead of at the route. But I dunno. There's gotta be a better way? This seems excessive to me.

```
Template.wordItem.helpers({
    wordObj: function () { 
        var controller = Iron.controller();
        var index = controller.params.wordIndex;
        var id = controller.params._id;
        var wordsObject = Decks.findOne ( id, 
                    { fields: { 'wordIds': 1 } } 
                );
        var wordId = wordsObject.wordIds[index];
        return Words.findOne ( wordId );
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample repository I've created which is very similar to what you are trying to do.

http://meteorpad.com/pad/xKS38qEZAieEPDyLs/Leaderboard

It seems to work. I suspect your problem is elsewhere.